# Warning: file_get_contents

Tags: php, xampp, host

I'm currently getting errors of

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\class.users.php on line 505
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://forum.habborp.com/habborp.php?type=VIP&username=&hotel_name=Yves) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\class.users.php on line 505

I was wondering if anyone could help with this maybe fix the whole file make it neat.

class.users.php: http://pastebin.com/HAaE78jK

Thank you :)

Comment: What happens when you try to access the URL manually, via your web browser?

Comment: the URL isn't working

Comment: Then how do you expect to `file_get_contents()` to work? It requires a valid resource.

Comment: It needs to be changed to something else as the URL isn't mine its supposed to get changed

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: to remove the dependence of the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to fix.

The error you are getting is because the source that your script is getting data from (forum.habborp.com) doesn't seem to exist anymore.

I'm not sure what kind of data used to be there, but your best/only best is to find a drop-in replacement for that or completely remove that dependence.

Can't offer another solution without knowing more about your project.

Comment: How can i complete remove its dependence?